# SharePoint REST Query expand Self Referenced Column

Tags: rest, sharepoint

I have two lists. Company and Employee. I have a lookup column called "company" in the employee list which points to the ID of the employee.

in my REST query, I can expand the title of the company very easily

```
http://abhi-sharepoint.abhishek.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$select=ID,Title,Company/Title&$expand=Company/Id&$filter=Company/Id%20eq%20%2714%27
```

Very good!

Now I add another lookup column to the Employee List called Manager and point it to employee id

Now how to I expand the ManagerId to manager title?

I tried

```
http://abhi-sharepoint.abhishek.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=ID,Title,Employee2/Title,Company/Title&$expand=Company/Id&$expand=Manager/Id&$filter=Company/Id%20eq%20%2714%27
```

I also tried

```
http://abhi-sharepoint.abhishek.com/sites/dev/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee2')/items?$select=ID,Title,Employee2/Title,Company/Title&$expand=Company/Id&$expand=Employee2/Id&$filter=Company/Id%20eq%20%2714%27
```

But nothing works. how can I use the expand on the same list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following REST endpoint

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$select=Title,Company/Title,Manager/Title&$expand=Company/Id,Manager/Id
```

returns `Employee Title`, `Company Title` and `Manager Title`, 
where `Manager` field is a `Lookup` to the same List

Example:

```
var query = "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Employee')/items?$select=Title,Company/Title,Manager/Title&$expand=Company/Id,Manager/Id";
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + query,
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){
      $.each(data.d.results, function(idx,item){
          console.log(item.Title); //Employee Title
          console.log(item.Company.Title); //Company Title
          console.log(item.Manager.Title); //Manager Title
      });
    },
    error:  function(data){
      console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
    }
});
```